# Batch check if variable is specific value

Tags: variables, batch-file, if-statement

I can not find solution (or is too complicated for me to understand), I would like to set variable by input

```
@echo off
set /p var="Choose (AV, RN or I) : " %=%
echo %var%
```

If value is one of these three then proceed (I will then use that variable to set path, copy,move,start...), else goto exit.

Answer (score 4):

```
if /i "%var%"=="AV" goto av
if /i "%var%"=="RN" goto rn
if /i "%var%"=="I" goto i

echo illegal input "%var%"
```

Quite what you want to do from there, you don't reveal.

The `/i` after the `if` means - ignore case. If you insist that the case should match, use `if "...` - that is, remove the `/i`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to achieve this is not checking the variable at all, but using its value in a `call` command with the error messages redirected to `nul`. This way, if the variable have some of the valid values, the appropriate routine is called; otherwise, nothing happens:

```
@echo off
set /p var="Choose (AV, RN or I) : " %=%
echo %var%
call :%var% 2> NUL
goto :EOF

:AV
echo Selected: AV
exit /B

:RN
echo Selected: RN
exit /B

:I
echo Selected: I
exit /B
```